# I want to load the background first using jquery but my code doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

Below is the code. but i don't know what the problem is. I have a array of background images after each load it keeps changing[This is my intention]. Now i planned to use javascript to load the background first but my code doesn't work though it works with regular style tags. I don't know what am doing wrong here. below are the code.

**This below code works but takes time to load the image**

```
<?php
  $bg = array('login_bg.jpg', 'login_bg2.jpg', 'login_bg3.jpg', 'login_bg4.jpg', 'login_bg5.jpg', 'login_bg6.jpg', 'login_bg7.jpg', 'login_bg8.jpg', 'login_bg9.jpg' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = $bg[$i]; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>



<style>

    body{
    background-image:url("<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>");
    }

    </style>
```

**This code doesn't work. I'm doing this because i want to load the BG first.**

```
<?php
  $bg = array('login_bg.jpg', 'login_bg2.jpg', 'login_bg3.jpg', 'login_bg4.jpg', 'login_bg5.jpg', 'login_bg6.jpg', 'login_bg7.jpg', 'login_bg8.jpg', 'login_bg9.jpg' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>

<script>
    var img1 = new Image();

    img1.src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>";


    $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+ img1.src + ')');

</script>
```

Comment: The code looks fine. What is $selectedBg? Does that contain extension like .jpg ?

Comment: yes it randomly selects images extending with jpg. i'll update that in question

Comment: "to load the background first" Does`body` exist at the time you're referring it? If the script is in `head`, `body` doesn't exist yet. Any error messages in the console?

Comment: you don't have random images you have this string "$bg[$i]"

Comment: see above that `$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);`

Comment: It should be like `$selectedBg = $bg[$i];`

Comment: why not  `$selectedBg = $bg[$i];` what's with the "", do you have any console errors?,are you loading jquery before or after this script tag?

Comment: that calls a string ..it call the name of the jpg file so it will be in string format. it works with or without "" this .. but the problem is in JS. the image keeps changing if i put it in style like this `<style>
 
 body{
 background-image:url("<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>");
 }

   </style>`

Comment: Yes, `$bg[$i];` is already a string, you don't need to use " "

Comment: @Jeeva You don't need to do this with the qoutes.

Comment: ya it works with or without `""` that is not the problem here

Comment: What do you mean by "keeps changing"? If you have set the css, it can't "keep changing" unless you're changing it somewhere else in your code?

Comment: _"but it takes time to load"_. Well, that's not really strange, is it? The image still needs to be downloaded to the client, regardless of your method of printing it out on the screen. Using jQuery, like you are now, should take even longer, since you need to download both the image _and_ jQuery before the image can be displayed..

Comment: So @magnus there is no way i can load BG image first.

Comment: You could "hide" all DOM elements by default, load the image (in a js Image, like you're doing right now) and have a "onload" callback on the image where you set the background image and then unhide all the DOM elements.

Comment: Just remember, If you go for the above approach and if someone is sitting on a slow connection, they won't see or be able to interact with your site at all before the background image is in place. In my opinion, that's kind of a bad UI and can make your site appear slow and sluggish.

Comment: thank you magnus. i'll try that. and thanks valuable suggestion. i'll find another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your path correct?

In my example, this would be this:

```
http://localhost/test/assets/images/login_bg.jpg
```

called from this file:

```
http://localhost/test/index.php
```

---

**Edit & Accepted answer:**

Your JS/jQuery is faster than your site. Try to use `$( document ).ready(function() {`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+ img1.src + ')');
});
```

### Why?

Because your site will be rendered from top to bottom. If you have JS/jQuery that will add something to your HTML, but the HTML is not rendered yet, it won't add something because jQuery will not find the item that you want to manipulate.

That's why you should include a JS-file at the bottom of your HTML-file.

But if you added it directly to your `<head>`, you have to it with `$( document ).ready(function() {` to be sure that your JS/jQuery will work.

Possible alternative is the standard JS onload function:

```
window.onload = function() {};
```

Comment: yes path is correct. I've updated by question pls refer

Comment: @Jeeva Edited my answer.

Comment: thank you atleast i got a solution for my problem, though it is not faster am satisfied with the answer and can say jquery doesn't load the image first. thanks again. peace.

Comment: @Jeeva I added some more information about this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify like this:

PHP:
It should be like `$selectedBg = $bg[$i];` instead of `"$bg[$i];"`

```
<?php
  $bg = array('login_bg.jpg', 'login_bg2.jpg', 'login_bg3.jpg', 'login_bg4.jpg', 'login_bg5.jpg', 'login_bg6.jpg', 'login_bg7.jpg', 'login_bg8.jpg', 'login_bg9.jpg' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = $bg[$i]; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>
```

HTML:

You need to add body tag also to get it working.

```
<body>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var img1 = new Image();

    img1.src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>";


    $('body').css('background-image', 'url('+ img1.src + ')');

</script>
</body>
```

Another thing:
Make sure `$base_url;` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like below.

```
<script>

    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(<?php echo $base_url; ?>assets/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>)');

</script>
```

Comment: `$('body').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png)');` just execute this from your browser's console and see what result you are getting.